# Bootstrap 3 - navbar collapsible until 990px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I've got this problem. Bootstrap 3 framework changes my navbar into collapsible version (mobile version) when it reaches 767px screen wide. I would like to change it that mobile version exists until 991px. I've seen a similar question but the correct answer is unusable for me. It says that it can be set up while downloading custom version of Bootstrap, putting required value for collapsible navbar. The problem is, I use it with Drupal 7 and the Bootstrap version is provided autamtically form this url: netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.css.

So I have to override this value in my custom css file, but I've know idea what to change - I believe there are many of classes to change. By the way, it might be important, I don't use LESS version.

Regards, 
David

Comment: Just include only Navbar styles by downloading using customize bootstrap. And include in your css file to override Bootstrap.css, and make sure that you include before Bootstrap is called. And change the @media queries from 767 to 991px.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override it like this..

```
@media (max-width: 990px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/105915

Comment: Awsome, thank you very much! I'm so glad you've given that code. I've downloaded custom version of Bootstrap and copied all the media queries <991 that had something to do with navbar but it didn't work. Propably something missed. Anyway, thanks again. Works like charm!